# Lan to wan setup

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, lan, internet-connection

I did factory reset on my second router by accident and since than I’m having issues sometimes. I would appreciate if someone can help me with router configuration, all I know is that first routers lan is connected to second routers wan- apparently lan to wan connection with cable.

My first router is on 1st floor:

- IP address 192.168.1.1,
- CHCP start from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.254
- Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
- Channel is set to auto

My second router tp link:

- **wan** dynamic ip,
- wan ip 192.168.1.2, default gateway 192.168.1.1
- **Lan**: 192.168.0.1
- CHCP 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.199.
  Default gateway 192.168.0.1
- Channel number 3

What do I need to change here to make wifi work without interruption?

Comment: Are the Wi-Fi SSIDs identical or different between the two routers?

Comment: They are different